# Possible to base GIS layers on results of calling API

Tags: qgis, api

Is it possible to call an API which returns spatial data as JSON, GML, XML for example and use it as as data source within QGIS or other GIS? I don't know enough about APIs to understand if I am asking too much of them and whether there needs to be some other steps to this. For example - how would multiple sets of parameters be passed and collated as single result sets? Should this be done via Python to call API multiple times, obtain data (how?) and then assemble in to a shapefile some how?

Comment: Can you add a more specific example of what you would like to achieve. The way it currently stands it's really hard to tell what your problem is and to formulate an answer.

Comment: Sounds like a WFS service would be easier https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wfs.html

Comment: Just to elaborate ... basically I am wondering if it is possible to call an API (possibly via WFS reference) to return output which can be plotted spatially. I'm suspecting the lack of obvious information suggests I'm on the wrong trail. By example, if an API takes a pair of coordinate and returns output (JSON or other) describing a route linking the two points, could this set of data be plotted in QGIS as a layer. Would it be better to assemble that data (possibly multiple pairs of origin / destinations) first and build a shapefile first?